# Disable user interaction with component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an Angular 2 application,when the user connect a loader is shown until the http request are finished,my problem now that i want to disable all interactions of users while the loader is shown 
Any solution?

```
<img *ngIf="isLoading"  src="http://mo16.alzheimersproam.ca/assets/images/blue-loading-wheel.gif" style="width:60px;background-position : center;position: fixed;" />
```

Comment: you are looking for a `router resolve`.show loading screen before component is loaded. check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) it has a question for this requirement . question 1

Comment: yes the loading is shown but my real problem is to disable all user interaction and its not working in this case

Comment: if you are using router resolve the component wont be show untill the loading is done can you throw some light